# How do I use axios to fetch data from API with different params using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to make a restaurant finder app & I am using an API [https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1'](https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1%27). So in that API, many ways are there to get data like based on location, shop name etc. So how do I implement that using Axios with hooks & also I should display?
or you can consider this question as how to perform api request & display on screen using axios with hooks ?

I am sharing my code below:-

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import zomato from '../api/zomato';

const SearchScreen = (props) => {

const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
const [results, setResults] = (['']);


/////// Making API request
/*
const searchAPI = async () => {
    //try{}
    const response = await zomato.get('/search');
   setResults(response.data.restaurants) ;

 };    
 */
const inputTerm = (event) => {
    setTerm(event);
};

return (

    <View>
        <SearchBar
            term={term}
            onTermChange={inputTerm} 

            onTermSubmit={searchAPI}
            />
        <Text> this is search screen</Text>
        <Text>We have found {results.length} result</Text>

    </View>

  );

};
```

So below I am posting searchBar.js file

```
 const SearchBar = (props) => {

return (
    <View style={styles.background}>
        <Feather style={styles.iconStyle} name='search' size={30
        } />
        <TextInput

            style={styles.textStyle}
            placeholder='Search' 
            value={props.term}
            onChangeText={props.onTermChange}
            onEndEditing={props.onTermSubmit}
            />
    </View>

);

};
```

this is my zomazto.js file
import axios from 'axios';

```
export default axios.create ({
baseURL: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1',

headers : {
    Authorization: 'Bearer e2ba1e85d07189511cade3ad235fd44c'
}
});
```

Comment: you didn't explain your question, when you wanted to load data from API?

Comment: I want to display restaurant details. example In the search bar I typed Italian dish. I should get the details of that on my screen?

Comment: okay i got it, let me explain.

Comment: I have looked into your code, you are doing right but are you facing some problem?

Comment: You just need to add params like this `/search?shop` or any other pram you wanted to add.

Comment: yes you are correct but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: see in the documentation `https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/common/establishments` there are so many options (categories, cities, collections etc). My question is how do I make a request to API & display them on screen ? (cities, collections, geocode etc)

Comment: You can add as many params as you want in your request as the below answer adds only one param and I think the below answer will also work for you if isn't then I will make a snack for you on the expo.

Comment: no, I am getting an warning 'possible unhandled promise rejection'

Comment: You promise is rejecting due to some missing param or improper request, can you make a snack on the expo with this expo and I will fix it.
https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: what is that & how do I share that >

Comment: You just need to create a new snack add your code in the snack and share the link here.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@hkbk9615/restaurant-

Comment: Save your snack, Copy and paste the link here.

Comment: is it working ???

Comment: It is showing the error because you haven't added dependencies in your package.json file

Comment: no. All those errors came after moving to snack. Instead you can make a new project & copy paste my folders on ur PC

Comment: Please add the exact version of your react-navigation, react-navigation stack in package.json.

Comment: Those errors whatever you are seeing in snack , it's not there in my VS CODE

Comment: yes, they will not be there but when you are running in your snack you have to add it.

Comment: Did you find my solution? @WaheedAkhtar

Comment: getting this error `{"code":403,"status":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid API Key"}` your token is valid one ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, You need to pass a query param into your request to find restaurants according to what you typed into the input in SearchBar component.

You don't need a hook here, just add the param into your request like:

```
/////// Making API request
const searchAPI = async () => {
   const response = await zomato.get(`/search?q=${term}`);
   setResults(response.data.restaurants) ;
};
```